# In what way do her breasts satisfy the husband of Proverbs 5:19

Tags: proverbs

> “a lovely deer, a graceful doe. **Let her breasts fill you at all times with delight**; be intoxicated always in her love.”
> ‭‭Proverbs‬ ‭5:19‬ ‭

In what manner are her breasts intended to generate delight? For example visually? Or through touch? Or orally? Or does it have nothing to do with the breasts at all, as the LXX seems to avoid them entirely in its translation of the text?

Comment: The later verse contrasts with 'a strange woman' and the context of the contrast is 'embrace' (according to KJV).

Comment: Disclaimer: this note sounds blunt, but that was not the intention.  I think the key is to read (or preferably, listen to: these scriptures were read to the people) Proverbs 5 in its entirety (as you no doubt have done, at least the reading part?). The point of the proverb you are looking at is to encourage faithfulness, not to explore the ways in which breasts delight the husband. When looking at a road, one asks “Where is this route taking me” - not “What is the Pantone code for this piece of gravel?”.

Comment: This, in my opinion, is the danger of pouring over texts in the way that you are doing, no doubt in a highly qualified and intellectually rigorous academic setting. Perhaps the high level of detail in the question belies YOUR greater context, however: perhaps you have done all of the above already.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to pin down a single way in which a wife's breasts delight her husband?

Comment: I believe the details of the "satisfaction" would vary widely from couple to couple.

Comment: You are all welcome to answer the question in the greater context of the paragraph, the chapter, the book or the whole Bible. The question is succinct but obviously clear and understood. Lastly the Bible (or it’s translators) chooses to touch upon this aspect of a husband and wife’s interaction, which means it’s important and understanding it properly has implication for a healthy, god ordained, god modeled marriage. This is not the first time the Bible speaks in this way and it does not shy away or treat it as a taboo topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Throughout the Bible, the Hebrew idiom of touching or fondling breast is a thinly disguised euphemism for sexual intimacy of the foreplay thereto.  Here is a sample:

- SS 4:5 - Your breasts are like two fawns, twins of a gazelle grazing among the lilies.
- SS 7:7, 8 - Your stature is like a palm tree; your breasts are clusters of fruit. I said, “I will climb the palm tree; I will take hold of its fruit.”
- SS 8:10 - I am a wall, and my breasts are like towers. So I have become in his eyes like one who brings peace.
- Eze 23:3 - and they played in Egypt, prostituting themselves from their youth. Their breasts were fondled there, and their virgin bosoms caressed.
- Eze 23:21 - So you revisited the indecency of your youth, when the Egyptians caressed your bosom and pressed your young breasts.

See also Gen 26:8.

In our text of interest, Prov 5:19, 20 we have:

> A loving doe, a graceful fawn— may her breasts satisfy you always; may
> you be captivated by her love forever. Why be captivated, my son, by
> an adulteress, or embrace the bosom of a stranger?

Note the chiastic structure:

A: may her breasts satisfy you always

- B: may you be captivated by her love forever
- B': why be captivated by an adulteress

A: or embrace the bosom of a stranger

The message is quite simple - satisfy you sexual intimacy needs at home with your spouse and NOT with anyone else.

Comment: I appreciate your response. It certainly fits the immediate and greater context. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

God created sex, between a husband and a wife, and God is good (Mt 19:17). Therefore, the enemy, those working against God, teach that sex is dirty (perhaps like trying to throw mud on God's robes). Rem. Peter was quickly rebuked by Jesus by his self-righteous response (Mk 8:33), which came FROM the enemy!

Please consider that when nursing, oxytocin (a pair bonding amplifier) is released in the woman and in the one nursing. This quiets the fear center in the brain , aids healing, lowers blood pressure, and builds connection (if it's a pleasurable experience) or it can encourage shunning if it's unpleasant, to protect the group. For some, this is an unpleasant experience that should be approached with compassion and lovingkindness at all times.

Prayer also releases oxitocin.

In nature, one can build a special bond with a canine for example, by chewing up food and feeding it to them. We shouldn't overlook the fact that there is something about the act of providing nourishment from one to another, in a loving way, which is God's way. Perhaps this may be a type of modeling or previewing "..I am the bread of life.."  as little or lesser Christians, this should not be overlooked. We are to model Christ on earth until He returns (1Cor 1:11 & others).

There is such a thing as being too righteous and overly wise (Ecc 7:16), and God put a play circuit in most if not all critters for a reason (of course being careful not to be the fool - aka perverting or going against God). ‭‭

Prvbs‬ ‭17:22‬ A joyful heart is good medicine,
But a broken spirit dries up the bones. (NASB 2020)

Rem to let your hair down, without sinning, and do what it takes to be cheerful : ) & to be at peace with one another as much as that is possible. A truly joy-filled, fun-loving follower attracts people to Love (the Author of Creation), through the Light that shines from above.
e.g. '..I want what they have. hmmm, if they are Christians, maybe I should re-think just what Christianity is.'

Be Good Do Good (ref Psa 119:68)!
..just as God is Good.

‭‭‭‭Isa‬ ‭66:10‬ ‭[10] “Be joyful with Jerusalem and rejoice for her, all you who love her; Be exceedingly glad with her, all you who mourn over her,
[12] For this is what the Lord says: “Behold, I extend peace to her like a river, And the glory of the nations like an overflowing stream; And you will be nursed, you will be carried on the hip and rocked back and forth on the knees. [13] “As one whom his mother comforts, so I will comfort you; And you will be comforted in Jerusalem.” [14] Then you will see this, and your heart will be glad, And your bones will flourish like the new grass; And the hand of the Lord will be made known to His servants, But He will be indignant toward His enemies. (NASB2020)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @ user62893 - While the info given is interesting, it doesn't deal specifically with the topic of the question about the "husband." Perhaps you could draft a different question that would address your answer on another posting.  Keep studying the Bible; it's great for the soul!